# How to avoid events to popup to accordion

Tags: events, accordion, vaadin-flow, stoppropagation

I have an Accordion Panel whose summary is a search field:

[image: Sample Screen Capture]

When the content of the search field change, the panel shall be opened and show search result.

It happens that the events in the search field pop-up to the the tab that consequently opens and closes the tab when space or enter keys are pressed. I tried to wrap the summary in a special div that prevents pop-up:

```
class MyDiv extends Div {
    public MyDiv(Component... components) {
      super(components);
      getElement().executeJs("addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {console.log('pop up prevented'); e.stopPropagation();});");
    }
  }

...

    accordion.add(searchAccordionPanel = new AccordionPanel(new MyDiv(searchField),
        searchItemsPage = new MenuItemsPage(this)));
```

And in fact I see the events intercepted ("pop up prevented" on console) but for some reason the accordion still responds to keypress. I have also tried keyup and keypress events, same result.

Maybe Vaadin transmit another event? Can anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

By default `TextField` is in eager value change mode, i.e. it emits value change after each key stroke. This does not fit in your use case. You can use `textField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY)` for example. Then `TextField` will emits value change after user has paused typing. There are also couple of other modes, pick the one that fits the use case the best. Some times it requires trial and error.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I already did to bypass the issue, but it is still a bypass and my question is more about event propagation. I could have a button instead of a text field and I don't want the events propagated to element containers.